# Grails3 restful api url mapping principle for multiple query purpose

Tags: grails, restful-url, url-mapping

I know the basic principle of Restful API design. I just want to know what I'm gonna do it with Grails3 URL mapping against multiple search actions.

I created the grails(3.3.9) app with the profile rest-API. The default UrlMapping.groovy looks like this.

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        delete "/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action:"delete")
        get "/$controller(.$format)?"(action:"index")
        get "/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action:"show")
        post "/$controller(.$format)?"(action:"save")
        put "/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action:"update")
        patch "/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action:"patch")

        "/"(controller: 'application', action:'index')
        "500"(view: '/error')
        "404"(view: '/notFound')
    }
}
```

Domain Class Example

```
class ProductSanpshot {
    String id
    Float price
    String name
}

class Order {
    String id
    String status
    Float totalPrice
    User createdBy
    List<ProductSanpshot> ProductSanpshots
    String remark
    Date dateCreated
}

class User {
    String id
    String name
}
```

Controller Example

```
class OrderController {
    def index() {
        respond(Order.list())
    }

    def show() {
        respond(Order.get(params.id))
    }
}
```

Based on the URL mapping set which satisfies the basic principle of the Restful design:

- When I access /order it would return the order list.
- When I access /order/1 it would return the order detail with id value 1.

My questions are:
Normally, we just don't get the order full list but with different parameters.
How can I map the URL to retrieve the order within a particular price range?
The normal implementation would look like this:

```
class OrderController {
    def index() {
        respond(Order.list())
    }

    def show() {
        respond(Order.get(params.id))
    }

    def getByPriceRange() {
        def minPrice = params.float("minPrice")
        def maxPrice = params.float("maxPrice")
        def result = Order.findAllByTotalPriceBetween(minPrice, maxPrice)

        respond(result)
    }
}
```

I would access order/getByPriceRange?minPrice=100&maxPrice=200.

I know this might not be so restful.

For default Grails url mapping I will get 404 error. It only maps http get to two actions to each controller. The index and show. And I don't think I have to map each controllers' actions one by one explicitly.

```
get "/$controller(.$format)?"(action:"index")
get "/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action:"show")
```

The other scenarios are:

- Get the orders by the status.
- Get the order's all product snapshots.
- Update the order's status
- Update the order's remark

What should I do with the UrlMapping to fulfill these needs by the restful way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrong about that and the url is still restful. Since it is a get request, you have to send your parameters in url. And it is good for several reasons. For example when you add that url to bookmarks, you will get the same result with the desired data without any problem (Especially if this url referring to a page). For my projects I am using National Bank of Belgium's rest [api design guide](https://github.com/NationalBankBelgium/REST-API-Design-Guide/wiki/REST-Resources-URIs). This was the most detailed guide that I can find and I really like it. You can see that they are using limit and offset parameters for pagination and sort parameter for sorting. In your example it is more like a search operation. Of course there are a lot of approach and I know about pretty much all of them but I really like their approach. I use FIQL for the searches. You can read about it Search/Advanced search section. I don't want to use different parameters for search so I use it like :

someUrl?q=minPrice=gt=10;maxPrice=lt=50

Could not find any library that I like so I wrote my own parser to resolve that. Anyway these are my opinions and as I can see there is no standard for these. I hope it helps and free free to ask anything. Cheers !!

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. My question is especially against Grails UrlMapping.
It only maps to two actions in controller. The index and the show actions.

Follow this principal I cannot find a common way to access the other http get actions just like getByPriceRange. It would return 404 error by now.


The same issue for http put. Let's say if I want to update the order's status or remark. Do I need two different actions? How to do the url mapping then. I cannot map every controller explicitly.

Comment: Well to do something like getByPriceRange (assuming your domain is Order), I would do the example I gave in my answer which is someUrl/orders?q=minPrice=gt=10;maxPrice=lt=50 (Get Request). And If you want to update something use PUT request or PATCH if it is partial update. In that case you can use the body. For example PUT someUrl/orders/id and the desired fields in the body. Since u specify the fields in the body, you don't need different actions. Single put or post mapping will do the job.

Comment: That sounds like I have to put all the query logic under index action and differentiate them by the parameters. Is this what you are suggesting?

Comment: Actually no. Edited my answer a lot of time because  accidentally pressed enter at the beginning. Read it again and lets think about it together.

Comment: Index action is just to get data. Let me explain with an example. Again lets assume you are working on Orders domain.  GET someUrl/orders gives you all orders (Assuming we didn't implement any search or pagination). But, GET someUrl/orders/1 gives you single order with id of 1. And lets say you want to update this order's status. Since this is a partial update we can use patch.  PATCH someUrl/orders/1 and the body is {status:false}.